# How to get value of String field from Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object that has a String field. I can obtain this field by calling:

```
Field field = someObj.getClass().getField("strField");
```

I sett a `Field#set(Object)` method, for setting the value of this instance's field, but the respective getter seems to be `Field#get(Object)`, which is weird because I would have expected it to be `Field#get()`.

How do I obtain the value of the instance's `strField`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are using `java.lang.reflect.Field`, the "setter" is `Field.set(Object,Object)` and the "getter" is `Field.get(Object)`.  in *both* cases, the first parameter is the instance on which you want to access the field.

Comment: Oh, he's really probably talking about `java.lang.reflect.Field`. Good catch!

Comment: @acdcjunior question was flagged with `reflection` tag so `java.lang.reflect` is first thing that comes in mind (at least for me :D). What was your other guess?

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, I brain farted. I thought `Field` was the class of `someObj` and the setters for `Field.strField` were `Field.set(Object)` and `Field.get(Object)`. His writing of `Field#set(Object)` (and not `set(Obj,Obj)`) made me completely misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

Even without the getter or the setter methods for a property, you can change or get the value using an object reference and Java Reflection.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Bean {

    private String strField;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        Field field = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField("strField");
        field.set(bean, "Hello");
        System.out.println(field.get(bean));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/):

```
String s = BeanUtils.getProperty(someObj, "strField");
```

Note that BeanUtils will attempt to convert your property into string. You need to have a getter and setter of the property